# Show build configuration in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have a project (C++ project within XCode 5) with multiple build configurations that I regularly switch between. Currently, to see the active configuration I have to click on the scheme and select 'Edit Scheme...' to view/change the configuration. It'd be nice to put this information somewhere more visible, or access it with a hotkey. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Command+Shift+< to open the "Edit Scheme...". You can change the hotkey in XCode->Preference->KeyBindings->Menu->Product Menu->Scheme-EditScheme

Comment: ahhh, there it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that I like is to create multiple schemes. Manage schemes and select your production scheme. Click the + button to add another scheme and name it with a -Dev postfix. Select the appropriate configuration.

Now you'll have multiple schemes that can be selected from the popup-menu easily for running and archiving.

[image: Scheme Menu]

Also by using this method, stored binaries in the Archive are tagged with the scheme name which can be useful.

[image: Archive]